# Davening and putting on tefillin when leaving early

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tefilin, zemanim

What are the guidelines for praying when one must leave early? For example, if one will be leaving at 6:45. נץ  is 6:52 and משיכר is 6:02.

What is the appropriate course of action? When can one Daven shachrit? How about putting on tefillin? Are tfilin necessary for davening shacharit, or can it be delayed until Mincha?

Answer (score 3):

Although you would ideally start *shmonei esre* at *netz hachama*, you can pray *shaharit* from *misheyakir* including talit and tfilin. In your case, you can start your *tfila* from 6:02 (see e.g., [here at chabad](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/134527/jewish/Zmanim-Briefly-Defined-and-Explained.htm) under misheyakir or [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=When_Is_the_Earliest_and_Latest_Time_to_Pray%3F))

What would be more tricky is if *misheyakir* would be at say 6:20 and you had to leave at 6:45. In this case you can say all prayers until *yishtabach* without talit/tfilin, wait for *misheyakir*, put them on at that time then continue. See [here on MY](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/procedure-for-pre-kevasikin-prayer).

If you cannot put on talit and tfilin in the morning, you can do so later until sunset (see [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos-2-mishneh-torah/407-times-wear-not-wear-tefillin/)), beyond that see [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1114).

Very nice summary by R Eliezer Melamed [here](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-11-07/).

As always, [ask your rav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) before applying anything you read here.

Answer (score 0):

there is an answer (see S.A) that when u have a market day and could not otherwise catch it, you could lay teffilin at misheyakir, I believe but ask your LOR (local orthodox rabbi)